Is there anyway to craft a PCAP from a CSV file?
I have easily converted a PCAP file to CSV file,  every packet of the pcap is presented as a row in the csv file & I believe none of the data is dropped during this conversion.
I have done this using 2 ways: Wireshark & CICFlowmeter.
Now, i want to convert this csv file back into pcap.
The Goal:
I am doing an experiment where I convert malicious pcap file into csv. I use this csv file as a dataset to train GANs(CTGAN).  The GANs give me new samples, call it Synthetic-Dataset, in csv format.
Now I want to convert this synthetic-dataset into PCAP and replay that PCAP under my IDS to see if the GAN was able to correctly generate synthetic attack data.
I have seen many research papers doing almost the same thing but they don't test their approach in real deployment. Instead they use other ML algorithms to check the closeness of original and synthetic data.

Did you store the actual binary data in the CSV?

I have done pcap -> csv in two ways.
First using Wireshark:
File-> Export Packet Dissections->As CSV.
This export method is not the best and i thought so because this methods stores the pcap data in the following format:
No. Time Source Destination Protocol Length Text item Info
1 0 95.143.193.132 95.143.193.131 TCP 62 �\234\223 2055  >  80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
2 0.000439 95.143.193.131 95.143.193.132 TCP 62 �\234\223 80  >  2055 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1.
This data is extremely difficult to handle in GANs too.

Secondly, i exported pcap->csv using CICFlowmeter.
It defines a fine grained csv file with 82 colums and values against them for each packet.
Then i used GAN on this data and, it was able to generate synthetic data.
Now I don't understand how can i used this synthetic data in actual network, to see how the security controls react to it.
I tried converting this csv to pcap again but unsuccessful

"pcap->csv" Does CICFlowmeter have a method that converts a CSV to PCAP? If not then you'll need to write your own
